# Machine Learning framework with Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, machine-learning, mahout

Which other frameworks exists besides Mahout for implementing Machine Learning algorithms in JAVA such that the underlying framework takes the JAVA code and runs it on Hadoop?

I am looking for alternatives to Mahout because I am need of a SVM and an Agglomerative Clustering implementation on Hadoop, and only SVM is supported in Mahout.

Comment: Ones that run natively on hadoop and are reliable/stable/mature/whatever? None that I know off. Could you say what's wrong with Mahout that you are looking for alternatives? That would make answering this question easier.

Comment: I created the non-distributed Mahout recommenders, and part of the Hadoop-based recommenders in Mahout. I'm currently working on a next-gen system based on Mahout, called Myrrix (http://myrrix.com), which includes a Hadoop-based recommender implementation. Not sure if it's what you're looking for, but if you are interested in Hadoop+Mahout it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you guys for Apache Hadoop based machine learning / data mining library like Apache Mahout.

http://www.openankus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2195722

It is so simple and easy mapreduce job processing. Are you interested in? See more wiki (http://www.openankus.org)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if SVM is on hadoop, the rest is easy to implement!

Note that naive agglomerative clustering algorithm is not efficient for large data ( O(n^2) complexity). Such complexity makes it impossible to run the algorithm on a large dataset, even on a big cluster, unless you try one of its extensions like this one: `ftp://193.167.42.127/franti/papers/GraphPnn-TPAMI.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

Pattern.  It has a Java API and you can use R too.

http://www.cascading.org/pattern/

Answer (score -1):

A quick Googling gave the following

http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/ - After close to 3 years, there was a release. Not sure how well it is supported and what algorithms are implemented.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/ - Some recent recommendations by others look good.

Also, see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829361/java-machine-learning-library-for-commercial-use).

**Haven't tried both of them.**

Comment: I do not believe they run natively on hadoop. Or do they?

Comment: These are not Hadoop-related. Weka is quite mature though.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I missed the Hadoop part.